# How to run `file` in powershell?

Tags: powershell

There's a program called `file` in my laptop's post BSD OS.

How to run a similar utility, in Microsoft PowerShell?

This is a bit hard to search, so I guess some experts exchange is required here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows comes with a utility which can identify files from their binary signature out of the box.
The closest I could find is [TrId file identifier](https://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) which has both command line and GUI versions.